# How to set the width and height as per container sizes?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have build a carousel but I want to make it responsive so when I resize the window it should resize itself.

I am using the following lines of code where I set the sizes but I want to do it by itself.

https://jsfiddle.net/6nhuk7vm/4/

```
var slideWidth = 1200;
var slideHeight = 300;
$('#slidesHolder').css('width', slideWidth * numberOfSlides);
$('#slidesHolder').css('height', slideHeight);
```

Comment: `max-width: 100%`...

Comment: you want to responsive make this slider according to container width and height?

Comment: If you are asking me if I want this slider to make it responsive the answer is yes

Comment: you want to keep fix width on this div `#slideshow #slideshowWindow, 1200px ` ??

Comment: no that's the initial size and when I make it smaller I want to scale

Comment: can i remove this `div` height `slidesHolder` from `js`?

Comment: do whatever you want

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should help, On resizing a function is triggered which adjusts all other height and width

```
$( window ).resize(function() {
    slideWidth = $(window).width();
    slideHeight = $(window).height();
    $('#slidesHolder').css('width', slideWidth * numberOfSlides);
    $('#slidesHolder').css('height', slideHeight);
    $('.img_tag').css('height', slideHeight);//change of height of image
    $('.img_tag').css('width', slideWidth);//change width of image
});
```

Also add this style

```
.slide{
   max-height:100%;
   max-width:100%;
}
```

Comment: have you tried this way? Because I just modified the code and there is no functionality after that

Comment: I didn't get you ... Can you be a little more descriptive as to what more functionality after this do you need?

Comment: I don't want more functionality. It kill my functionality. Can you update the JSFIddle and then post it here?

Comment: Hi Markus, check this link https://jsfiddle.net/6nhuk7vm/15/ you basically need to arrange the container as well as the image dimensions. I have changed my code above also. Let me know if this works

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the [JSFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/sznx95dd/16/)

The key thing to take is the complete lack of any fixed pixel definitions anywhere in the build. Obviously there are other things, like position and overflow that one might expect to see in a simple slider and several colours added to slides for clarity.

Sliding left and right is handled by animating `left` by `100%` which takes it's value from the parent container.

Slide sizes are calculated in JS and kept as % too.

The parent `.slider` class is set to `50%` so when you resize the JSFiddle output panel it resizes too; then the rest of the % styles kick in the whole slider squashes or stretches. When coupled with using % is the javascript the result is a slider that responds to it's parent size including it slide distances.

This can probably be tidied up further. I think some of the calculation could be removed from the JS with a bit of thought and refactoring.

Please note, the html and body tag 100% settings were just put in to help with the way JSFiddle rendered and aren't necessary, I just didn't want to set fixed pixels at the top level of the example DOM and have you change them to see the effect - this way the JSFiddle panel resize works